# Transform a 2x2 array into a 2x2x2 arrays with numpy

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I use numpy to do image processing, I wanted to switch the image to black and white and for that I did the calculation in each cell to see the luminosity, but if i want to show it i have to transform a 2d array into 2d array with 3 times the same value

for exemple i have this:

```
a = np.array([[255,0][0,255]])
#into
b = np.array([[[255,255,255],[0,0,0]],[[0,0,0],[255,255,255]]])
```

I've been searching for a while but i don't find anything to help

PS: sorry if i have made some mistake with my English.

Comment: your solution looks more like a 2x2x3 instead of a 2x2x2 to me. If you have three times the same value, then one of the dimensions must be 3.

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to us an explicit broadcast: https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.broadcast_to.html#numpy.broadcast_to

```py
b = np.broadcast_to(a[..., np.newaxis], (2, 2, 3))
```

Usually you don't need to do it explicitly, maybe try and see if just `a[..., np.newaxis]` and the standard broadcasting rules are enough.

Answer (score 0):

Another way to do it

```py
np.einsum('ij,k->ijk', a, [1,1,1])
```

It's a way to create a 3 dimensional array (hence the `ijk`), from a 2d array (`ij`) and a 1d array (`k`). Whose result is for all i,j,k being indices of `a` and of `[1,1,1]`, the 3d matrix of `a[i,j]×[1,1,1][k]`.